# having different kind of backgrounds for a page divided into horizontal sections

Tags: css, responsive-design

I warned you, I can be a little vague

Anyway, what I am after are those pages that fill the whole screen, but if you scroll down and you come to a different section ( some specific content or just a footer), it breaks away from the previous content by having a different background.
Sorry, if I sleep on it, I can maybe come up whith a better explanation and/or an [example page](https://paiq.nl/).

Does that style have a name and how is it done? If it needs to be responsive?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's simple to do. Setup like so, and customize to your heart's content.

```
<div id="header" class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
[...]
</div>
</div>

<div id="feature_area" class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
[...]
</div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
[...]
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
[...]
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The parent (container) `<div>`s will stretch to 100% page width. The child (wrapper) `<div>`s will stretch to 70% of their parents (or, you can set this to fixed pixel dimensions and change based upon screen dimensions) and will be centered. You apply decorative backgrounds to the parent `.container` like:

```
#header {
    background: #ff0000;
}

#footer {
    background: #000;
}

#content {
    background: url(img/bg_pattern.gif);
}

#feature_area {
    background: url(img/hero_feature_img.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: is this also responsive

Comment: It will need more CSS substance to be responsive, but yes, if you use percentage-based dimensions, it will always fill the screen no matter the device.

Comment: I mean the footer like the example page before scrolling stays in the same position?for the most part, I get it. I will figure out the rest.

Comment: I don't see it stay in the same position before scrolling, perhaps I need to look in a different browser. You can use CSS `position: fixed` to affix that particular `<div>` to one place